# Unable to Retain Values of Views in Expandable ListView

Tags: android, checkbox, state, expandablelistview

I have Expandable Listview having Different views Like EditText, CheckBox, DateTime Picker etc.
Now the issue is that while scrolling the List or collapsing the group, all the values get lost.
Please suggest me any way by which I can retain my values.

Comment: you need to specify explicitly what goes at each position in `getView()`. ex. if position (you need one for group and child) is 2 then this layout, if 5 then this. if your layout are too convoluted, there's always trying to re-invent the wheel with a table layout too. you can collapse it.

Comment: Are you using view holder ?

Answer (score 0):

its better you store all the values entered in a arraylist and notifydatasetchanged each time the user click on different list item or collapse the list view